# Как читать файл одновременно из нескольких потоков

Tags: c#

```cs
using (var stream = File.Open(@"./Files/HelloSticker.tgs", FileMode.Open))
{
    InputOnlineFile iof = new InputOnlineFile(stream);
    iof.FileName = "StickerHello.tgs";
                
    await client.SendDocumentAsync(userId, iof, replyMarkup: new ReplyKeyboardMarkup(new MainKeyboard().OpenMainKeyboard(), true), cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
}
```

Написал такой код, но возникает следующая ошибка

```
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Метод SendDocumentAsync из бибилиотеки Telegram.Bot

Comment: Как вы поняли, что он открывается синхронно? Это важно, потому что скорее всего ваш диагноз ошибочный. В чем именно проблема?

Comment: @aepot System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. Возникает следующая ошибка

Comment: Подсказка наугад `File.Open(@"./Files/HelloSticker.tgs", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)` - оно?

Comment: Так это дело не в асинхронности, файловая система на низком уровне всегда синхронная. Если же речь об асинхронности на уровне CLR - тоже не в ней проблема. Просто в следующий раз пишите более простыми словами "хочу читать файл одновременно из нескольких потоков". Многопоточность != асинхронность.

Comment: @aepot, вроде помогло, а в чём магия?)

Comment: Магия именно в `FileShare.Read`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Попробуйте исправить открытие файла так, чтобы при открытии разрешался доступ на чтение другим потокам - `FileShare.Read`.

```cs
var stream = File.Open(@"./Files/HelloSticker.tgs", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
```